# Determining if Point is within an Enclosed Way in OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

Given a GPS point, we want to check if it is within a parking area. Typically, parking areas in OSM have the amenity:parking key value pair and also are defined as a way that looks like a closed shape. If the search radius of the query has part of the shape boundary in it, then it will return the parking tags. But, if it is within the shape and not intersecting the boundary, then it doesn't return any tags. **Is there a way to determine if that GPS point is within the shape to then return its tags?**

We know there is a solution to load all parking lots within a certain area (e.g. a whole state or city) and then check if your GPS point is within any of them but this isn't ideal.

Comment: "If the search radius of the query has part of the shape boundary in it, then it will return the parking tags." What query are you talking about? Overpass API? If so then please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I create an overpass query that uses a bounding box and searches for specific tags I specify within that box. Also, just so you know I am running a Overpass OSM local server on my machine. An example of the query I send it would be the following: <osm-script output="xml" timeout="30">
<union>
<query type="way">
<has-kv k="amenity" v="parking"/>
<bbox-query e="-84.38402482779472" n="33.777159623691844" s="33.77696770876241" w="-84.3842557148148"/>
</query></union>
<print/>
</osm-script>